# How to add drivers to Windows 7 installation DVD?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, installation

How I can bundle newer or missing drivers to Windows 7 DVD?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you’re familiar with Windows XP Service Pack slipstreaming, this is pretty similar.

I’m using Windows XP Professional for this example. It should be similar with Vista etc.

Make ISO image from your Windows 7 DVD with your favorite software. I used [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/).

Save **install.wim** somewhere on your hard drive from that ISO image or straight from DVD.

Download Windows Automated Installation Kit for your OS ([Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=696DD665-9F76-4177-A811-39C26D3B3B34&displaylang=en), [Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C7D4BC6D-15F3-4284-9123-679830D629F2&displaylang=en), [XP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C7D4BC6D-15F3-4284-9123-679830D629F2&displaylang=en)).

Start *AIK Deployment Tools Command Prompt* from *Start* menu

```
cd <path where you saved that wim file>
```

Mount the WIM image with write permissions:

imagex will tell which number is which Windows edition if it’s not found. I tried it first with just number 0.
Number 4 is in this case Windows 7 Ultimate Edition 64 bit.

```
imagex /mountrw install.wim 4 c:\wim
```

Add as many drivers as you like by using DISM. If DISM says that files are essential for booting but drivers are unsigned, then add `/forceunsigned` parameter.

Here’s example for nVidia nForce drivers (Installer EXE extracted with 7-zip):
SATA/SATARAID/IDE/Ethernet/etc drivers:

```
cd c:\dl\15.51_nforce_win7_64bit_whql\ide\win764\
dism /image:c:\wim /add-driver /driver:. /recurse

cd c:\dl\15.51_nforce_win7_64bit_whql\smbus
dism /image:c:\wim /add-driver /driver:. /recurse /forceunsigned

cd c:\dl\15.51_nforce_win7_64bit_whql\smu
dism /image:c:\wim /add-driver /driver:. /recurse

cd c:\dl\15.51_nforce_win7_64bit_whql\ethernet
dism /image:c:\wim /add-driver /driver:. /recurse
```

..and so on for all needed drivers..

***You will need to expand unexpanded driver files in some cases***. Drivers are not expanded if filenames in driver directory are **foo.dl_** and not **foo.dll** etc.

Here’s NVidia GeForce driver sample for you (Installer EXE extracted with 7-zip)

```
cd c:\dl\191.07_desktop_win7_winvista_64bit_international_whql
mkdir c:\displaydriver
expand *.* c:\displaydriver
```

and then

```
cd c:\displaydriver
dism /image:c:\wim /add-driver /driver:. /recurse
```

Save the WIM image with new drivers:

Unmount and commit (commit = save)

```
imagex /unmount /commit c:\wim
```

Add the **install.wim** back to the ISO image with your favorite ISO handling software. I used UltraISO. Make sure that the DVD is bootable. Burn ISO as new DVD yet again with favorite burning software (CDBurnerXP).

Boot and enjoy your new Windows 7 with correct and working drivers.

Comment: pretty fast to answer your own question :) i suppose this is your own website? http://raspi.fi/

Comment: Yep. SU is safer place for this howto if my site goes down someday. I struggled with this driver bundling whole day and night yesterday. :)

Comment: I'm glad you did it in wise foresight :)

Comment: Uuuughhhhh, I wish you would have said that UltraISO has a long (apparently manual) registration process. :( I placed an order but have NO KEY... sitting here waiting and waiting and waiting and I don't have an entire weekend to spend on this... very frustrating :( If you're reading this and you hope to get "instant satisfaction" with UltraISO, think again -- expect to make this a multi-day process because they can't be bothered to have an automated registration system.

Comment: Should the drivers be installed in any order, e.g. chipset drivers first? Or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 3):

I want just to add a complement, if you need the drivers at the installation time (Ex: storage device etc.), you need to do this procedure for boot.wim too:

boot.wim have 2 installation embedded.

so you do the procedure twice:

```
imagex /mountrw boot.wim 1 c:\wim
add your drivers
imagex /unmount /commit c:\wim

imagex /mountrw boot.wim 2 c:\wim
add your drivers
imagex /unmount /commit c:\wim
```

Another info:

Remove the file `ei.cfg` from the DVD source folder, then you will be able to select the windows 7 version you want to install (Home, Pro, Ultimate etc).

then to be sure that your drivers ares available for each version, you must do the procedure for `install.wim` for each version embedded in `install.wim`.

```
normally X = 1, 2, 3, 4 for the command:

imagex /mountrw install.wim X c:\wim
add your drivers
imagex /unmount /commit c:\wim
```

and repeat for each possible `X` number

You can find the available `X` with:

```
imagex /info install.wim
```

by looking at the `INDEX` attribute of the `IMAGE` element in the XML printed by the `imagex /info` command, e.g.:

```
<IMAGE INDEX="4">
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can make ISO from the DVD, edit the ISO (rewrite it) by adding files to it (for example in \drivers\ folder) and burn the ISO again to DVD. Therefore you can access the drivers on the DVD after the Windows installation.