# windows 7 Slipstream drivers to the install dvd/iso

Tags: windows-7, drivers, slipstream, dism

I would like to know how can I slipstream drivers into the installer correctly.
I know that I can insert inf files with dism but I'm wondering, whats up with driver install packages like a bluetooth package? Ok I can extract the inf file from an exe if its embeded but on my laptop if I install the BT only with INF, windows recognises it as a bootrom device.
Or there are drivers which has additonal gui interfaces like Intel GMA, Realtek HD audio, etc..
And finally whats up with the cat files? If I remember right the INF files are linked to cat files.
For examle:`CatalogFile.NT = XY_Device.cat` so if the cat file isn't embeded into the install.wim how will it work?

So is there any way to slipstream any kind of driver into the windows install whitout sysprep and imageX because thats not an option for me, because my Windows is an OEM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lot of software to do it, it is explained here (RT7Lite is an option if you don't want to install the full AIK):

[How to add drivers to Windows 7 installation DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/63773/how-to-add-drivers-to-windows-7-installation-dvd)

drivers are ALWAYS only inf files that copy dlls and any other needed file in system folder.

most devices come with a management software, usually installed as "driver": this software is an addition to drivers (e.g. realtek audio drivers are a few kBs, but to install them using their installer you "have" to install a lot of things, like the realtek control panel).
Integrate those apps can be difficult (if they don't support silent install you will actually see the installation procedure launched at the end of windows install).

you can slipstream ANY version of windows (retail, oem...) just taking the original DVD anc using the entire content in the procedure linked before.