# How to embed wireless network drivers in iso file

Tags: windows, installation

I want to know how to embed wireless network drivers so that i do not need to install drivers after clean installation of windows.

Comment: I am trying to perform a clean installation of windows 8.1 and want wireless drivers to be Pre-installed.

Comment: Yes; I understand what you want to do.  You have to install Windows, install the driver, then create the image of the installation to do that.

Comment: This is also known as [`slipstreaming`](http://superuser.com/questions/63773/how-to-add-drivers-to-windows-7-installation-dvd)

Comment: NTLite and Winreducer are paid. Is there any freeware to do slipstreaming ?