# Creating a bootable CD to install all tablet drivers

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, drivers

I've got a strange question here.  I'm currently installing a special version of Windows 7 on a tablet, and upon install, I obviously lose all tablet functionality such as the touch screen.  I'm also hitting a second problem, I have one USB port, and when I get to the login screen, my peripherals fail to work so I can't use either a mouse or keyboard. They work just fine in the bios.

So my only thought on how to make this work would be to somehow create a bootable CD that will install all the Windows 7 drivers. Is this possible? can anyone think of an alternative route? I can't install a different image.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the CD to be bootable if all you are doing is using it to install drivers to an existing operating system?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton I can't use a keyboard or mouse when booting to the operating system.

Comment: Also: [How to add drivers to Windows 7 installation DVD?](http://superuser.com/questions/63773/how-to-add-drivers-to-windows-7-installation-dvd)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this before, but I've heard of people bundling in drivers WITH their Windows installer.

Windows provides the tool 'Windows Automated Installation'. One such use for this tool is to bundle in drivers with a Win7 ISO. 
Here's a related question that covers that topic. [How to add drivers to Windows 7 installation DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/63773/how-to-add-drivers-to-windows-7-installation-dvd)

Also, Lifehacker.com has an article on (what looks like) an easy, point-and-click  method of doing something similar. http://lifehacker.com/5793427/how-to-create-a-custom-windows-installation-dvd-or-usb-install

I can't speak for the success of either of these methods, but I do know it's possible.

Comment: This is certainly the way I would prefer to do it, thank you for this. But I can't actually change the install ISO. It has to stay "as-is" sadly.

Comment: @Brian5193 What is the issue with modifying the ISO? It's likely this is your best, if not only, option.