# Windows 7 Installation does not detect Hard Disks

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, drivers

I started a clean install of Windows 7 on my new laptop. But it neither detect the touch-pad nor the Hard Drives so I cannot install the Windows on them.

Is there a way to get Windows 7 detect the laptop's internal hard disks?

Comment: the touchpad thing's common just pop in a mouse and try downloading and installing the driver. In some cases downgrading the driver's handy. It might also be worth considering a VHD install of windows 7 over nuking the windows 10 install totally. assuming this is cause some hardware's not supported.

Comment: what steps are you following when you are trying to install? provide more info

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, your new laptop is using a SATA controller that is newer than what was shipped when Windows 7 was released.  If Windows doesnt have the driver for the SATA controller, it cannot see any disks that are connected to it.

You should be able to go to your laptop manufacturer's website and download the SATA controller drivers needed. You will need to copy these drivers to a CD or USB stick.  Make sure to unzip/pack them before copying them to the disk.  During the Windows 7 installation, I believe at the point you are getting stuck at (I havent installed 7 in a long time, so my memory is failing me) there is an option to load additional drivers.  Select this and navigate to your CD or USB drive to install the driver.

Once the drivers are installed, you should see the drives connected to the SATA controller.

As for the touch pad... Im not sure, generally touch pads should work as a generic mouse and dont need a special driver.  I would simply install Windows and when its done installing, it should hopefully autodetect it.  If not, use a regular mouse to make your life easier and go back to the laptop manufacturers website and dowload the touchpad driver.

Answer (score 1):

If you can confirm the hard disk on the laptop is ok, try to load the disk driver which downloaded from the OEM website during the installation. Unzip and copy the driver to a USB device, and ensure the USB device will be detected during the OS installation.

[image]

Also, if you built a USB installation image already, you can consider to import the related driver to the Win7 install image, please refer to : [How to add drivers to Windows 7 installation DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/63773/how-to-add-drivers-to-windows-7-installation-dvd)

you can use DISM GUI too to import the driver instead of using the commands. https://dismgui.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

you can enter BIOS and change disk controller mode from IDE to AHCI for performance or from AHCI to IDE for compatibility

[More Info: http://www.diffen.com/difference/AHCI_vs_IDE](http://www.diffen.com/difference/AHCI_vs_IDE)

Comment: it is ahci and has no other options to choose.

Comment: @iranano that is unusual. you might be looking at the wrong page. also: are you sure your hard disk is healthy?

Comment: yes. it is a new laptop.

Comment: @iranano tell me your model number so that I can check if it's a common ahci controller which windows would recognize during strartup. also, are you sure that your pc is booting from a windows 7 usb or dvd?